# Why "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5' " Error keeps showing?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to install PyQt5 in any possible way, but when I run the code, I get a traceback " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5' "

[image]

Comment: how you run the program? Do you run the program in the same environment you installed PyQt5?

Comment: Which command did you use to install the module and on which OS are you on?

Comment: I used " pip install PyQt5"

Comment: How can I find the environment where I installed PyQt5?

Comment: @Tito use `python -m pip install PyQt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc it tells me No module named pip

Comment: @Tito If you don't have pip installed in the python you use to run the script then I installed the pip you used to install PyQt5 in another python

Comment: See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that could have gone wrong:

1. You installed the module incorrectly. Have you used it before, or is this your first time importing it? Also, did the console/terminal say it was installed? If you quit too soon, it will not download.
2. It is in the wrong folder. If it downloads successfully, it should be with your other modules, in the lib or usr folder in python. if you need a list of all modules, just use help("modules")